# Change font in my document-class

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I created a new documentclass that is based  on the `\documentclass{article}` . I would like to use the font **Barlow** that I just downloaded. I use the package `fontspec` and the compiler **XeLaTeX**.

When I create a document of the class `\documentclass{article}` it seems to work: the font I want is correctly used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=./Barlow/,
Extension= .ttf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
ItalicFont= *-Italic,
BoldFont= *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

Test here.
\end{document}
```

But when I use the mydocumentclass I created it does not work: the font seems to be set to default.

```
\documentclass{mydocumentclass}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=./Barlow/,
Extension= .ttf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
ItalicFont= *-Italic,
BoldFont= *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

Test here.
\end{document}
```

I also tried to paste the following code in the `mydocumentclass.sty` and `mydocumentclass.cls` of my template:

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=./Barlow/,
Extension= .ttf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
ItalicFont= *-Italic,
BoldFont= *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]
```

It does not print any *Error*, but rather seems to be overwriting my font. And In which document should I paste this piece of code? Or should I proceed in a different manner ?
Thank you by advance !

Comment: Difficult for me to understand the problem without knowing the contents of `mydocumentclass.sty` and `mydocumentclass.cls` files. Maybe there is some `\AtBeginDocument` somewhere?

Comment: if it works for `article` but not for `mydocumentclass` then there is code in that class resetting the font but if you show no code it's not going to be possible to help you.  The path option looks a bit suspicious though, you are specifying a fixed path to the font from the current directory in which xetex is running. That is not typically going to be true for a class and font that are installed site wide with xetex running in the directory with the document.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by removing from the `mydocumentclass.sty` the command : `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}`. It forced the font to be *Sans Serif*. It wrote the following code in the file `mydocumentclass.sty` :

```
\setmainfont{Barlow}
[Path=./Barlow/,
Extension= .ttf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
ItalicFont= *-Italic,
BoldFont= *-Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]
```

Thank you for your help!